# Show orders in datagridview2 when select a specific user in datagridview1

Tags: c#, database, master-detail

I have 2 datagridviews, the first for the users and the second for their orders. When I want to select a user in the first datagridview it should show their orders. Both orders and users contain the CustomerID to match them.

```
namespace NorthWind_Application


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers;", conn);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Customer c = new Customer();
                c.CompanyName = rdr["CompanyName"] as String;
                c.ContactName = rdr["ContactName"] as String;
                c.Address = rdr["Address"] as String;
                c.City = rdr["City"] as String;
                c.Country = rdr["Country"] as String;
                c.Phone = rdr["Phone"] as String;
                c.CustomerID = rdr["CustomerID"] as String;


                customers.Add(c);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customers;
        }



    }

    private void DataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer c = (Customer)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = " + c.CustomerID, conn);
           //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Orders;", conn);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Order> order = new List<Order>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Order o = new Order();
                o.OrderID = (int)rdr["OrderID"];
                o.CustomerID = (string)rdr["CustomerID"];
                o.OrderDate = (DateTime)rdr["OrderDate"];
                o.ShipName = (string)rdr["ShipName"];
                o.ShipCity = (string)rdr["ShipCity"];
                o.ShipCountry = (string)rdr["ShipCountry"];


                order.Add(o);
            }
            dataGridView2.DataSource = order;
        }
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

When I start the application I get 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'ALFKI'.' '

ALFKI is a CustomerID.

Comment: Start by never creating SQL using string concatenation.  Always use parameters.  Always

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: I'd probably use strongly typed datasets for this. Problem is it'd take quite a long time to type out how to do it and it would be better to demonstrate it visually (screen recording)